# Analyzing the behavior of the ODE $2y'-y = e^{\frac{t}{3}}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE

$$2y'-y = e^{\frac{t}{3}}$$
with $y(0) = a$

And I'm suppose to do these things with it:

(a) Draw a direction field for the given differential equation. How do solutions appear to
behave as t becomes large? Does the behavior depend on the choice of the initial value
a? Let a 0 be the value of a for which the transition from one type of behavior to another
occurs. Estimate the value of a 0 .

(b) Solve the initial value problem and find the critical value a 0 exactly.

(c) Describe the behavior of the solution corresponding to the initial value a 0 .

So here's my sketch of the direction field:

[image]
I'm supposing $y'=-1, y'= 0, y'=1$, and I got these graphs. I can see that if I put a particle in the blue graph, it'll end up going downward, thus diverging to $-\infty$. The same for the purple graph and the ones below it. Now, for things above the blue graph, I assume that for small displacements of the blue graph, the particle could have a chance of going to $-\infty$, and I'd guess that for curves like, when $y(0) = 2$, the particle would go to $+\infty$, so this is my guess for $a_0$. The book, however, says it's $-3$, which I didn't understand.

Also, in the process of solving the EDO, I got:

$$y(t) = -3e^{\frac{t}{3}}+ce^{\frac{t}{2}}$$

$$y(0) = a \implies a = -3+c \implies c = a+3$$

therefore:

$$y(t) = -3e^{\frac{t}{3}}+(a+3)e^{\frac{t}{2}}$$

Here I can see that $a = -3$ would make the function go to $-\infty$, but I can't see how this $-3$ relates to the $2$ that I found for the initial value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y(t) = -3e^{\frac{t}{3}}+ce^{\frac{t}{2}}$ is the correct general solution and as a consequence $c=a+3$ .

There is no mistake in Guerlando's calculus (not considering the graphical interpretation).

Obviously, the term $ce^{\frac{t}{2}}$ is the leading term when $t\to\infty$ . Thus, if $c>0$ , when $t\to\infty$ then $y\to+\infty$

Hence, $c$ must be negative or zero if we want $y(t)$ tends to $-\infty$.

Since $c=a+3$ the condition for $y(t)\to-\infty$ is $c=a+3\leq 0$
$$a\leq -3$$

The mistake is in the interpretation of the graph. By the way, this is the graphical representation of something as a function of something. But what as a function of what ? This is not made clear on the figure. The key point is here. I suppose that you can take it from here.

HINT :

The figure below shows the trajectories $y(t)$ drawn in black for various initial points $(x=0,y(0)=a)$. The particular trajectory for $y(0)=a=-3$ is drawn in red.

Of course, it isn't asked to draw them with a computer software as it was donne. But one can roughly sketch them.

The blue curve is not a trajectory, but it is the geometrical locus where $y'(t)=0$.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I did the wrong graph